# Wrong parameter passed in the constructor. How can I fix it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I've published a crowdsale contract with a wrong parameter. How can we fix this?

Can I contact Etherscan for help, or is the only option to publish a new contract?
Is it a problem to have two similar published contracts, but with different parameters passed in the constructor?

Answer (score 4):

> How can we fix this?

If you havn't included a function to do so, not at all.

> Can I contact Etherscan for help

I don't mean to be rude here, but if you are not clear about how etherscan and your contract are in relation to each other, you should not conduct crowdsale. In your and your buyers best interest.

> is the only option to publish a new contract?

If there is no function to change that var, yes, you must publish a new contract.

> Is it a problem to have two similar published contracts, but with different parameters passed in the constructor?

No.

Comment: And one more question :) My etherscan account is connected to the published smart contract. And I have an icon and social media links? Should I create a new account and connect it to the new smart contract with the correct parameters?

Comment: That depends on how much of your crowdsale you already registered with etherscan, can you provide the etherscan your contract uses ?

Comment: I did Contract Source Code Verified. 
And also Update Token Information with my etherscan account. So i have an icon and all social media connected to the token address.
This is everything that I did in ether scan. The crowdsale is not started, so i have enough time to deploy a new contract.
I see that I can create another request in etherscan to update token information. So hope to works and to be updated with the new contract address

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan can't do anything for you, it just displays public data.

Ethereum is a decentralized (no authorities) and immutable (no rollback) database.

You have only two options:

- In your crowdsale implementation, if there is a function to update the state of your parameter, you can call this function by sending a transaction.
- If there is no such function. You have no choice than deploy a new instance of your contract. You can deploy as much contract as you want with same or different parameters... Each contract instance is unique and addressable via is unique address.

Comment: There is no update function...
Is it a problem to have two exactly the same contracts with exactly the same token names?

Comment: nope... it's not a problem. you can deploy the same contract as much as you want

Comment: And one more question :) 
My etherscan account is connected to the published smart contract. And I have an icon and social media links? Should I create a new account and connect it to the new smart contract with the correct parameters?